# Auto-fill username and password in Fluid.app webapp

Tags: web-app, fluid.app

I'd like to have my [Fluid.app](http://fluidapp.com/) webapps auto-login to various sites (Gmail, DropBox, etc.) using passwords stored in AgileBits [1Password.app.](https://agilebits.com/onepassword)

I'd appreciate directions or suggestions on how to go about this, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

1Password only integrates with a browser that supplies an API which Fluid does not see this thread on [AgileBit's website](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/20788/fluid-alternatives) and Fluid does not seem to be able to read any OS APIs to get stored information

[Patrick Welker](http://rocketink.net/2014/08/1password-for-fluid-with-keyboard-maestro.html) has used using Keyboard maestro to copy around but this uses Apple's keychain, I have not tried this